# Cesium model loading from GLB/GLTF not loading material

Tags: cesiumjs, gltf

I've generated a generated a GLB file using khronos's SharpGLTF libraries and have got the model loading in cesium, the model appears correctly. The problem is the material for the model does not show. I have tested the generated GLB in other viewers and the material does show.
I'm using the following code in cesium:

```
var entity = viewer.entities.add({
name : 'url_here',
position : center,
orientation : orientation,
model : {
    uri : 'url_here',
    minimumPixelSize : 128,
    maximumScale : 20000,
}
});
```

also tried

```
var model = scene.primitives.add(Cesium.Model.fromGltf({
    id: 'here',
    url: 'url here'
    modelMatrix : modelMatrix,
    scale : 1.0,

}));
```

I've tried using the color modifiers for cesium and the only option that responds is "color" which doesn't help as it doesn't apply any lighting to the color.

Below is a picture of what cesium is outputting. However there should be more effects to the material than just red. It seems to respect only KnownChannel.BaseColor and that's it.

[image: cesium image of model]

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you share any screenshots, or a sample model that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Just added one, hopefuly shows what I'm getting and what I'm trying to show on screen.

Comment: Do any errors show up in the web console?  Is the texturemap being loaded in the network tab (for .gltf only, the network tab won't show a separate texture loading from inside of a .glb file).  Also can you run the glTF Validator on the model, and does it pass?

Comment: It is valid. I believe I solved it. The sun wasn't in the right position to cast shadows. Seems to be partially working now, still not as nice as it could be but I'm playing with it.